# How to detect last record, delphi

Tags: delphi, firedac

Weird question, but this is where I'm at.
I have a next/previous button on a form, which goes next/prior on the dataset.
I have code disables previous when BOF, and disables next when EOF.
problem is those flags not getting to BOF/EOF, unless I go PAST the first/last record, so I have to click them twice when I am at the first record, or at the last record.
Using recno won't work because of sorting stuff (already tried that)
so, how do I detect the first and last records?

Comment: Have you tried [TDBNavigator](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TDBNavigator)?

Comment: doesn't fit the design

Comment: If you don't like the design of TDBNavigator, you can still use the TDataSetAction derivates declared in Vcl.DBActns.pas. Although that won't solve your problem, it can spare you some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Eof`:

```
  DataSet.DisableControls;
  try
    DataSet.Next;
    if not DataSet.Eof then
      DataSet.Prior;
  finally
    DataSet.EnableControls;
  end;
```

Similar for `Bof`.

Comment: so, call next/prior twice.
tricky!